# Reactjs Invalid DOM property error on SVG elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, webpack

I am working on code refactoring on a React project. It has components like this

```js
import * as React from "react";

function SvgPage(props) {
  return (
    <svg width="100" height="100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
  </svg> );
}



export default SvgPage;
```

These SVG files render without any issue but in the console, it gives me the error

> Warning: Invalid DOM property `stroke-width`. Did you mean
> `strokeWidth`?

How do I get rid of these console warnings? I search google and find [SVGR](https://react-svgr.com/) library. But I am not sure how to use it to fix the problem.

any help!

Thanks in advance! =)

Answer (score 9):

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#specifying-attributes-with-jsx),

> Since JSX is closer to JavaScript than to HTML, React DOM uses `camelCase` property naming convention instead of HTML attribute names.
>
> For example, `class` becomes `className` in JSX, and `tabindex` becomes `tabIndex`.

Replace hyphenated prop names with their camelCase versions.

```
<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" strokeWidth="4" fill="yellow" />
```

Answer (score 2):

[I think this is your error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOCnT.png)

so you have to change attributes inside the svg tag to use camel case, like
`stroke-width="4"` as `strokeWidth="4"` and
`stroke-linecap=""`   as `strokeLinecap=""`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Comment: What does this add to the already provided answer?